# break syntax error: Syntax Error

Tags: python, syntax, break

What is wrong with my break? I don't get why it say that invalid syntax on my break when i compiled the code

```
for index, (start, end) in enumerate(searchPFAM(fname)):            
    with open('output_'+uniprotID+'-%s.txt' % index,'w') as fileinput:
        print start, end
        for item in lookup[uniprotID]:
            item, start, end = map(int, (item, start, end)) #make sure that all value is int
            if start <= item <= end:
                print item
                result = str(item - start)
                fileinput.write(">{0} | at position {1} \n".format(uniprotID, result))
                #text = fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
                textwrap.fill(''.join(makeList[start-1:end],width = 60)
                break
            else:
                fileinput.write(">{0} | N/A\n".format(uniprotID))
                #text = fileinput.write(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]))
                textwrap.fill(''.join(makeList[start-1:end],width = 60)
```

Comment: is it tab-sensitive and your else: statement is in line with the for statement?  I know py is touchy on that.

Comment: Shall I post that as an answer if that helped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on this line:

```
textwrap.fill(''.join(makeList[start-1:end],width = 60)
#            ^       ^                                ^
```

It should be this:

```
textwrap.fill(''.join(makeList[start-1:end]),width = 60)
```

Comment: good catch.. thanks but it should be parenthesis after end]

Answer (score 1):

It is the missing right parenthesis on the previous line.